# Wake-Up Dormant Electric Motorcycle Battery

Tags: lithium-ion

I have a 2010 Zero DS electric motorcycle with a very depleted battery.  I estimate it has been off charger for approximately 1.5 years.  The bike has been stored inside a garage in a dry environment.  I have the original charger.  Is it safe to simply plug in the battery and charge?  Should I take some other steps to "wake-up" the dormant battery ahead of full charging?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Unfortunately a battery of most any type that is 'dead' for a long period of time suffers from metallic salts that form, and expand with time. This is what your electrolyte decays into. These salts act like short circuits and the battery will not charge or hold a charge. You can give it a try, but count on buying a new battery.

Comment: You should say what the battery chemistry is.  It makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I found the specs and it says a patent pending Lithium Hybrid Array,

> Using an advanced monitoring system, each cell in the power pack is individually controlled during charge and discharge. The onboard charger integrates into this system and uses a specially developed charge profile to optimize the power pack’s recharge time. Using isolated power systems the Zero DS uses a standard 12 volt current to run the dash, lighting and other on board accessories.

Usually excessive UnderVoltage state must be very time limited and long term is fatal to performance.  But saying that, you would get best advice from the OEM.

But it appears to have all the design features to just plug in and hope for the best.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in Li-ion battery packs the BMS (Battery Management System) cuts off the battery to prevent overdischarge when the per-cell voltage drops below, say 3.0V. In this situation, the pack can only be recharged.

The BMS then goes into a low power state in order to prevent a deep discharge of the battery pack, but it continues to drain small amount of current from the battery, which progressively lowers the pack's voltage. It is very common for a BMS to completely forbid the recharging when the battery is deep discharged, i.e. <2.0V/cell, in order to prevent catastrophical damage to the cells ad surroundings.

So, I would say that yes, it is safe to connect the original battery charger, which is very likely communicating with the BMS. But if the battery is not recharging, this could be because of his deep-discharged state. In this case, you'll probably need professional assistance from the OEM.